# Importing all functions from a python source code file in a class definition and provide them via property

Tags: python, source-code-protection

Is it possible to include all functions from a python source code file "functions.py" in another source code file with a class definition "my_class.py" and provide these functions via property "my_functions" to the user?

Example:

```py
**functions.py**

   def function1()
   def function2()
```

```py
**my_class.py**

   class my_class():

      @property
      def my_functions(self):
```

So, is it possible to access to this functions "function1, function2" via the object property from the class "my_class":

```py
**main.py**

   my_class_object = my_class()
   my_class_object.my_functions.function1()
   my_class_object.my_functions.function2()
```

Comment: Why did you tag this question both `python-3.x` and `python-2.7`? This question doesn't appear to be version specific.

Comment: What happened when you tried using the `import` statement?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? I don't think this needs to use `property` in any case. You can just add the module as a regular attribute of the class.

Comment: I tried it with the ```import``` statement but how can i access the functions via the property?